# Exclude 10.63.128.0 10.63.255.255 or 10.63.128.0/17 range from 10.0.0.0/10

Tags: cisco, ip, ipv4, acl

Please help to suggest a method to exclude IP range 10.63.128.0 10.63.255.255 from 10.0.0.0/10.

I have a access list 3100 to filter the traffic  with `rule 10 10.0.0.0 0.63.255.255` and now I have to exclude a pool 10.63.128.0 10.63.255.255 from this acl 3100  and apply to acl 3110 in OAM service traffic classification.

```
acl 3100
rule 10 10.0.0.0 0.63.255.255 ## how can I implement to exclude this 10.63.128.0/17 network rage
acl 3110
rule 10 10.63.128.0  0.0.127.255
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you add an ACL entry *before* the larger range for the smaller range. So, in case you want to exclude (=permit) 10.64.128.0/17 from a general deny for source net 10.0.0.0/10:

```
10 permit ip 10.64.128.0/17 any
20 deny ip 10.0.0.0/10 any
```

The first ACL entry that matches is used. Most often, your entries are sorted by prefix length from longest (=most specific) to shortest (=least specific).

Comment: Great!! Logic is fine, but I have to match all traffic of 10.0.0.0/10 which will pass 10.0.0.0 to 10.63.255.255 except 10.63.128.255 to 10.63.255.255. this last block of /17 subnet used for other classification in same router. Could you please review and suggest ?

Comment: Just swap `permit` and `deny` in the example.